# Eerase userData from previous stage in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have discovered that when I replace the scene from game to menu, and then trying to go back to game, the userData is somehow full , and the contact listener is reading something and try to act so i get crash.

I have this line in the contact :

```
if( bodyA->GetUserData() !=NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() !=NULL)
{
CCSprite *actora = (CCSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData();   
CCSprite *actorb = (CCSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData();
```

and before I replace my scene I destroy all bodies ,but somehow when I go back into the game scene,the user data is full and this condition is true at the moment the scene is ON, and it crash .That's because there isn't really any sprite or body on screen.

How can I delete the userData before replacing a scene ?
How to remove my sprites from UserData?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have this code in your dealloc method?

```
delete world;
world = NULL;
```